# How to repair OSM file with missing nodes

Tags: openstreetmap, osmium

I'm using [osmium-tool](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) to create OSM history extracts, and then import then into Postgres using [osm2po](http://osm2po.de). This is causing problems when the ways do not have referential integrity (i.e., some nodes are missing from some ways). After the osm2po import, the missing nodes are placed at lat, lon ~(215,215).

I can see the likely problem in osmium. Running

`osmium check-refs tmpExtract_DEU_0.6.osm.pbf`

yields:

`There are 10668502 nodes, 1647384 ways, and 0 relations in this file.
Nodes in ways missing: 116607`

I'm happy to drop the ways that have missing nodes, but I don't see a way to do this in osmium. Is there any way to clean the osm file and ensure referential integrity?

To clarify, osmium's `check-refs` command is useful, but is there a way to fix things if `check-refs` highlights a problem?

Comment: Have you figured it  out ?

Comment: My workaround was to use the `osmium extract` command to clip to a polygon, and then use the `simple` option to drop nodes outside the polygon. But a more elegant solution would be nice.